# extjs4 TypeError: store is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am a newbie for extjs4. I am reading the application architecture in the extjs offical website which offered a simple example([application_architecture](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/application_architecture)). But I encountered some issues when studying this case.

[image]

The app sturcture in eclipse is like above. The question I met is regarding the ***store***.

*app\controller\Users.js*
**please look at the comment in this piece of code.**

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: [
        'AM.store.Users'  //this line of code can't work, unless I update it to `Users`
                          //or it will report the exception 'TypeError: store is undefined'
    ],
    models: [
        'AM.model.User'
    ],
```

Now I pasted the code of the other files related to this issue.

*app\store\Users.js*

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.User',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'data/users.json',
            update: 'data/updateUsers.json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

I have searched for the exception in google, but got nothing helpful, and I have debugged it in firefox, still nothing, maybe because I am an expert in javascript.
I also checked the source code of other extjs apps in the company I worked, I found the **controller** can refer to the **store** like **'AM.store.Users'**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use the command "sencha app build" from Sencha Cmd, it should tell you what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer your store as `'AM.store.Users'` by adding an entry in your app.js config for stores like below similar to controllers.

```
stores:['Users']
```

Please try it once,hope it will help you.

Comment: I added it in app.js, but does not work. thanks anyway.

Comment: Its working for me try it out here http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/community/extjs4-mvc-basic-array-grid   register the store in your app.js and refer it in your controller.

Comment: sorrr..  I didn't find the store registered in app.js on http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/community/extjs4-mvc-basic-array-grid/viewer.html. I only saw controllers: [
        'Stocks'
    ],

Comment: Yes add the entry in app.js like i said  and refer your store in controller as you  intended like  'Am.store.Users'.You will see its working fine

Comment: Ext.onReady(function(){
// alert("ok");
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
           layout: 'fit',
           items: [
               {
                   xtype: 'userlist'
               }
           ]
        });
    },
    controllers: [
                  'AM.controller.Users'
              ]
    ,
    stores:['AM.store.Users']
});

});

Comment: In app.js just add stores:['Users'] ,it will identify the folder structure,no need to add 'Am.store.Users' .

Comment: I tried, it works, thank you,But actually in controller if I removed the AM.store, just use     stores: [
        'Users'
    ],  it will work fine.  I just think it's two weird why it cannot work if I add the Am.store

Answer (score 0):

app.js shouldn't be modified with significant logic as it will be rewritten on every framework update